# Extreme mouse lag in Starcraft I using VirtualBox Mac Host, Windows 7 Guest

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, gaming, starcraft2

I've installed virtual box on my new MacBook Pro and I'm hosting a Windows 7 instance. Everything works very smoothly.

However, I've installed the original Starcraft (yes, 1995! It's 20 years old!) and when I go to use it the mouse response is very laggy, probably 2-3 seconds - which renders the game completely unplayable.

Any hints here? I have increased the video memory to 128mb. The game requires very little resources, so I'm quite sure it's not a hardware issue.

Comment: Why aren't you using bootcamp instead?  I suspect that would solve your problems.

Comment: @MBraedley Boot Camp is not virtualization, it requires that you restart your entire system in Windows. Obviously it would work, but this is a convenience issue.

Comment: It's no different than what Linux dual booters have had to do for ages.

Comment: I am seeing the same thing, except I am using Windows XP as the guest VM. Have not determined what the lag is from. Sometimes it is minimal, sometimes it is a good 5 seconds, even 10 on occasion. I tried more system RAM, video RAM, more CPUs, played with other settings also. Still looking for a solution. Of course, I tried it in BootCamp also with no problem.